# wp insert post infinite loop

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Using a script to automatically create posts on wordpress from the data stored in the database, problem is it is creating thousands of the same posts, instead of just 1.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `proccessed`= 0 ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;"; // products
$result = mysqli_query($mysql_link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{


                    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_title' => $row['name'],
        'post_content' => $row['description'],
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Can be draft, pending or any other post status
        'comment_status' => 'closed', // if you prefer
        'ping_status' => 'closed', // if you prefer

        ));

    if ($post_id)

        // Insert post meta (ACF Custom Fields)


echo $row['name'].' posted<br>';
}
```

Comment: well, how many rows is the first SELECT query returning?

Comment: It is returning all the rows, but when finishing the last row it starts over

Comment: It should be impossible - mysqli_fetch_assoc will return NULL when no more rows are left, and then the while loop will stop. So I'd have to assume something else is calling this bit of code repeatedly.

Comment: This is the tutorial I used, https://imelgrat.me/wordpress/bulk-upload-custom-posts-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting a result based on your query.  You are always getting based on a product ID order, but where processed = 0...  Lets say you have only 2 records in your table.  Record 1 is Product ID 1 and is processed = 0. Same with product ID 2 processed = 0.

You keep adding records to the table, yet your original record 1 is always the one being added since it is never being updated to a status as Processed.  Each subsequent is processed.  As you add records, what is the Processed status on those.  Since we are not seeing a processed status via any update, nor default insert, I can only assume a numeric default is zero.  So, is every record now being qualified as it is consistently being added to the database?

Unsure based on the brief context of your example.